# Sort Array of Dictionaries by Key Value and if keys are equals sort alphabetical order within itself

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I have an Array of Dictionaries given in bellow;

```
{
      "result": [
           
            {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "AKILLI",
                "sequence": 1,
               
            {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "DİĞER YEDEK ",
                "sequence": 2,
            },
            {
                "id": 61,
                "name": "TELEFON",
                "sequence": 0,
            },
            {
                "id": 62,
                "name": "TABLET",
                "sequence": 0,
            }
     ]
     }
```

I want to sort this array using;

```
 self.currArray = currArray.sorted { $0.sequence < $1.sequence }
```

The result is;

```
 {
      "result": [
            {
                "id": 61,
                "name": "TELEFON",
                "sequence": 0,
            },
            {
                "id": 62,
                "name": "TABLET",
                "sequence": 0,
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "AKILLI",
                "sequence": 1,
               
            {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "DİĞER YEDEK ",
                "sequence": 2,
            },
            
     ]
     }
```

Also ı want to sort using name when "sequence" is the same. And ı want to get;

```
{
  "result": [
        {
            "id": 62,
            "name": "TABLET",
            "sequence": 0,
        },
        {
            "id": 61,
            "name": "TELEFON",
            "sequence": 0,
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "AKILLI",
            "sequence": 1,
           
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "DİĞER YEDEK ",
            "sequence": 2,
        },
        
 ]
 }
```

How to sort array using this two option together? Firstly ı want to sort array using "sequence" key if key is equals secondly sort "name" key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a convenience syntax using tuples and you can sort in place

```
self.currArray.sort{ ($0.sequence, $0.name) < ($1.sequence, $1.name) }
```